# C++ use class with conversion operator as index into array

Tags: c++, conversion-operator, array-indexing

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Id, typename Value>
class sparse_set {

  static_assert(std::is_integral_v<Id>, "");  (1)
  static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<Id>, "");

  Value& operator[](Id id);

  void push_back(const Value& value);
 
  // class implementation left out

};

class entity {

public:
  explicit entity(std::uint32_t id) : _id(id) {}
  ~entity() = default;

  std::uint32_t id() const {
    return _id;
  }

  operator std::uint32_t() const {  (2)
    return _id;
  }

private:
  std::uint32_t _id;

}; // class entity

int main() {
    const auto e = entity{2};

    auto set = sparse_set<entity, int>{};

    set.push_back(0);
    set.push_back(1);
    set.push_back(2);
    set.push_back(3);

    auto i = set[e];  (3)
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use a class with a `conversion operator` to `std::uint32_t` (2) as an index into a container class (3).
Accessing an element with an instance of that class works and i get the right element.

But testing the class with a `static_assert` and `std::is_unsigned_v` and `std::is_integral_v` results in an assertion failure.

I need assertions to make sure `Id` can be used as an index.

When I `static_assert` with `std::uint32_t` everything works so I would expect the conversion operator to work aswell.

Comment: Is `entity` (Id) an integral type? I don't think so.

Comment: No, `static_assert(std::is_integral_v<entity>);` would complain. "_Provides the member constant `value` which is equal to `true`, if `T` is the type `bool`, `char`, `char8_t` (since C++20), `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, or any implementation-defined extended integer types, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants. Otherwise, value is equal to `false`._". Also note: "_The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `is_integral` or `is_integral_v` (since C++17) is undefined._"

Comment: your code has several errors not related to the question. Please fix them and also add the necessary includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::is_unsigned` and `std::is_integral` only works for primitive types, it doesn't work for classes, even if they are implicitly convertible to a type they support. You can solve this by two ways:

1. Create your own trait:

   ```cpp
   #include <type_traits>

   // ...

   using uint16 = std::uint16_t;
   using uint32 = std::uint32_t;

   class entity { /* ... */ };

   template <typename T>
   struct is_valid_index : std::is_unsigned<T> {};
   template <>
   struct is_valid_index<entity> : std::true_type {};

   template <typename T>
   constexpr auto is_valid_index_v = is_valid_index<T>::value;

   template<typename Id, typename Value>
   class sparse_set {
       static_assert(is_valid_index_v<Id>, "");
       // ...
   };

   // ...
   ```
2. Remove `std::is_unsigned` completely and use `std::is_convertible` instead:

   ```cpp
   #include <type_traits>

   // ...

   using uint16 = std::uint16_t;
   using uint32 = std::uint32_t;

   class entity { /* ... */ };

   template<typename Id, typename Value>
   class sparse_set {
       static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Id, uint32>, "");
       // ...
   };

   // ...
   ```

Comment: isnt anything that `is_unsigned` also `is_convertible_v<T,uint32>` ?

Answer (score 4):

`entity` certainly is not an integral type. It can be converted to a type that can be used as index and thats what you require:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Id, typename Value>
class sparse_set {

  static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Id,size_t>, "");

  // class implementation left out

};
```